# Decide class for Jackson deserialisation based on JSON value of a specific key

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have some JSON to be deserialized into POJOs. Which class to use is dependent on the value of a certain key in the received JSON. A simplistic description of the problem:

I have

```
{"type":"animal","name":"Kitty"}
```

This should be deserialized into

```
public class Animal {
  public Animal(String name) {}
}
```

I have

```
{"type":"staff","name":"Peter"}
```

This should be deserialized into

```
public class Staff {
  public Staff(String name) {}
}
```

How do I archieve this with the latest Jackson (2.9.4 as of this writing) as JSON engine? So far, I have not found anything in the documentation which has enlightened me...

Comment: You don't know in advance whether you're getting a staff member or an animal?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Comment: You could use a customer de-serializer for this, but I suspect the issue is a design one to start with: if you don't know which to expect between staffers and animals, you are likely doing something wrong prior to de-serialization (and I'm trying very hard to not make puns about staff being a bunch of animals - oops).